# Reading data from a UNV file

Tags: python

I wrote a Python code to extract Data from UNV file. I am facing out of bound error Issues.
I need to extract the Boundary Groups data (From lines: 1270 to 1357). The error is given below.
There are 2 Boundary groups: SOURCE AND WALLS: In the UNV file, there will be 2 blocks of each Boundary group: 1. The first part is Boundary face data, 2. The second part is Boundary NODE data (I want this data to be extracted). This group data of Node which I wanted to extract is from Lines 1270 to 1357.
UNV File Link: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/idnryyzhumr53tfrzvjkb/Mesh_5x5x5x.unv?rlkey=h8ck16r90d5u2wxoy7hljfjvs&dl=0

````
    from collections import defaultdict
    import numpy as np
    from tqdm import tqdm
    import os, sys
    import math
** # This is the UNV file**
    input = open('Mesh_5x5x5x.unv','r')
    output = open('co-ordinates.txt','w')
    output2 = open('nodes.txt','w')
    output3 = open('connectivity.txt','w')
    output4 = open('boundary_2_6.txt','w')
    data = input.readlines()
    print(len(data))
    input.seek(0)
    x= []
    y=[]
    z=[]
    node=[]
    conn1 = []
    conn2 = []
    conn3 = []
    conn4 = []
    boundary = 0
    boundary_list = []
    boundary_names = defaultdict(list)
    boundary_names_2_5 = defaultdict(list)
    boundary_index = []
**READING THE DATA FROM UNV FILE**
    for line in data:
        if line.strip().lstrip() == '2411':
            start_index = data.index(line)
        if line.strip().lstrip() == '2412':
            stop_index = data.index(line)
        **READIG THE COORDINATE DATA FROM UNV FILE**
    for i in range(start_index+1,stop_index-2,2):
        l1 = data[i].strip('\n \t').lstrip().split()
        node.append(l1[0])
        l2 = data[i+1].strip('\n \t').lstrip().split()
        x.append(l2[0])
        y.append(l2[1])
        z.append(l2[2])
        #print (l1)
        #print (l2)
** # READING CONNECTIVITY OF FACES**
    for line in data:
        if line.strip().lstrip() == '2412':
            start_index = data.index(line)
        if line.strip().lstrip() == '2467':
            stop_index = data.index(line)
    for i in range(start_index+1,stop_index,1):
        if len(data[i].strip().lstrip().split())==4:
            conn1.append(data[i].strip().lstrip().split()[0])
            conn2.append(data[i].strip().lstrip().split()[1])
            conn3.append(data[i].strip().lstrip().split()[2])
            conn4.append(data[i].strip().lstrip().split()[3])
**# READ BUNDARY INFORMATION: ELEMENTS AND NODES:**
**HERE I AM PAERICULARLY INTERESTED IN EXTRACTING NODE DATA WHICH IS CONTAINED IN THE LAST GROUPS : SOURCE **AND WALLS (LINES 1270 TO 1357)**
    for i in range(stop_index+1,len(data),1):
        #print('DDD:',i,stop_index+1) 
        if data[i].strip().lstrip()[0].isalpha() == True:
            print('DDD:',i,stop_index+1,len(data))
            boundary_names[data[i].strip().lstrip()]
            boundary_names_2_5[data[i].strip().lstrip()]
         #exec(data[i].strip().lstrip()+'=[]')
         #exec(data[i].strip().lstrip()+'_2_5=[]')
            boundary = boundary+0.5
            boundary_list.append(data[i].strip().lstrip())
            boundary_index.append(i)
    print(boundary_list)
    print(boundary_index)
    print(len(boundary_index))
    bnd_index = boundary_index[len(boundary_index)//2:]
    bnd = len(bnd_index)
    #bnd = 4
    print('bnd',bnd)
    #
    for l in range(bnd):
        print(l)
        print(boundary_index[l+2])
        print(boundary_index[l+1])
        lines = (boundary_index[l+3]-boundary_index[l])-3
        print("lines=",lines)
        for k in range(lines):
            #print("k=",k)
            #print("l+1+k=",l+1+k)
            p = data[bnd_index[l]+1+k].split()
            print("p=",p, len(p))
            #for j in range(len(p)):
                #if float(p[j])>-0.001:
                    #boundary_names[data[bnd_index[l]].strip()].append(p[j])
                    #exec(data[bnd_index[l]].strip()+'.append(p[j])')
            if (len(p)>1):
                p = data[bnd_index[l]+1+k].split()
                boundary_names_2_5[data[bnd_index[l]].strip()].append(p[1])
                boundary_names_2_5[data[bnd_index[l]].strip()].append(p[5])
                #exec(data[bnd_index[l]].strip()+'_2_5.append(p[1])')
                #exec(data[bnd_index[l]].strip()+'_2_5.append(p[5])')
```
**OUTPUT:**
**p= ['7', '14', '0', '0', '7', '15', '0', '0'] 8
p= ['7', '16', '0', '0', '7', '7', '0', '0'] 8
p= ['7', '29', '0', '0', '7', '30', '0', '0'] 8
p= ['7', '31', '0', '0', '7', '32', '0', '0'] 8
p= ['7', '1', '0', '0', '7', '5', '0', '0'] 8
p= ['-1'] 1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\jnanadeepti\prasad\coding2023\lbm-python\3d\3d-flow\readunv\read_unv-test.py:88
    p = data[bnd_index[l]+1+k].split()

IndexError: list index out of range**
    `
````

Comment: Any clues or tags to clarify what a UNV file is? Or what app creates such things? Or a sample file?

Comment: There are two different SOURCE and WALLS sections.  Why choose one over another?

Comment: Dear Tim, The first SOURCE is FACE data and the Second SOURCE is Node data. Same with WALLS data. I use the Node data for my 3D LBM code. Earlier I hard coded input geometry data. Now I am updating my code so that I can read data from UNV and use it in my CODE instead of hard coding the geometry info. This will help me to use my code to various complex geometries and make it robust.

Comment: Dear Mark, UNV is file format used for CAD geometries. All CAD modelling software (For example Salome an Open source CAD software can export CAD geometry to UNV along with many other formats. UNV is a simple format compared to CGNS.). I shared the sample file. Please see the Link under my problem explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extracts all the data from all of the SOURCE and WALLS section in an easy way.  Perhaps you can modify this to get what you need.  You're going to a lot of totally unnecessary work.

If you only want to keep the second SOURCE/WALLS sections, just set `source = []` after `state = 1`, and `walls = []` after `state = 2`.

```
from pprint import pprint

f = open('../Downloads/Mesh_5x5x5x.unv', 'r')
state = 0
source = []
walls = []
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if line == 'SOURCE':
        state = 1
    elif line == 'WALLS':
        state = 2
    elif line == '-1':
        state = 0
    elif state == 1:
        source.append([int(i) for i in line.split()])
    elif state == 2:
        walls.append([int(i) for i in line.split()])
pprint(source)
pprint(walls)
```

Output:

```
[[8, 186, 0, 0, 8, 187, 0, 0],
 [8, 188, 0, 0, 8, 189, 0, 0],
 [8, 190, 0, 0, 8, 191, 0, 0],
 [8, 192, 0, 0, 8, 193, 0, 0],
 [8, 194, 0, 0, 8, 195, 0, 0],
 [8, 196, 0, 0, 8, 197, 0, 0],
 [8, 198, 0, 0, 8, 199, 0, 0],
 [8, 200, 0, 0, 8, 201, 0, 0],
 [8, 202, 0, 0, 8, 203, 0, 0],
 [8, 204, 0, 0, 8, 205, 0, 0],
 [8, 206, 0, 0, 8, 207, 0, 0],
 [8, 208, 0, 0, 8, 209, 0, 0],
 [8, 210, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125],
 [7, 3, 0, 0, 7, 53, 0, 0],
 [7, 54, 0, 0, 7, 55, 0, 0],
 [7, 56, 0, 0, 7, 45, 0, 0],
 [7, 46, 0, 0, 7, 47, 0, 0],
 [7, 48, 0, 0, 7, 13, 0, 0],
 [7, 14, 0, 0, 7, 15, 0, 0],
 [7, 16, 0, 0, 7, 7, 0, 0],
 [7, 137, 0, 0, 7, 138, 0, 0],
 [7, 139, 0, 0, 7, 140, 0, 0],
 [7, 141, 0, 0, 7, 142, 0, 0],
 [7, 143, 0, 0, 7, 144, 0, 0],
 [7, 145, 0, 0, 7, 146, 0, 0],
 [7, 147, 0, 0, 7, 148, 0, 0],
 [7, 149, 0, 0, 7, 150, 0, 0],
 [7, 151, 0, 0, 7, 152, 0, 0],
 [7, 29, 0, 0, 7, 30, 0, 0],
 [7, 31, 0, 0, 7, 32, 0, 0],
 [7, 1, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0],
 [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 136]]
[[8, 111, 0, 0, 8, 112, 0, 0],
 [8, 113, 0, 0, 8, 114, 0, 0],
 [8, 115, 0, 0, 8, 116, 0, 0],
 [8, 117, 0, 0, 8, 118, 0, 0],
 [8, 119, 0, 0, 8, 120, 0, 0],
 [8, 121, 0, 0, 8, 122, 0, 0],
 [8, 123, 0, 0, 8, 124, 0, 0],
 [8, 125, 0, 0, 8, 126, 0, 0],
 [8, 127, 0, 0, 8, 128, 0, 0],
 [8, 129, 0, 0, 8, 130, 0, 0],
 [8, 131, 0, 0, 8, 132, 0, 0],
 [8, 133, 0, 0, 8, 134, 0, 0],
 [8, 135, 0, 0, 8, 136, 0, 0],
 [8, 137, 0, 0, 8, 138, 0, 0],
 [8, 139, 0, 0, 8, 140, 0, 0],
 [8, 141, 0, 0, 8, 142, 0, 0],
 [8, 143, 0, 0, 8, 144, 0, 0],
 [8, 145, 0, 0, 8, 146, 0, 0],
 [8, 147, 0, 0, 8, 148, 0, 0],
 [8, 149, 0, 0, 8, 150, 0, 0],
 [8, 151, 0, 0, 8, 152, 0, 0],
 [8, 153, 0, 0, 8, 154, 0, 0],
 [8, 155, 0, 0, 8, 156, 0, 0],
 [8, 157, 0, 0, 8, 158, 0, 0],
 [8, 159, 0, 0, 8, 160, 0, 0],
 [8, 161, 0, 0, 8, 162, 0, 0],
 [8, 163, 0, 0, 8, 164, 0, 0],
 [8, 165, 0, 0, 8, 166, 0, 0],
 [8, 167, 0, 0, 8, 168, 0, 0],
 [8, 169, 0, 0, 8, 170, 0, 0],
 [8, 171, 0, 0, 8, 172, 0, 0],
 [8, 173, 0, 0, 8, 174, 0, 0],
 [8, 175, 0, 0, 8, 176, 0, 0],
 [8, 177, 0, 0, 8, 178, 0, 0],
 [8, 179, 0, 0, 8, 180, 0, 0],
 [8, 181, 0, 0, 8, 182, 0, 0],
 [8, 183, 0, 0, 8, 184, 0, 0],
 [8, 185, 0, 0, 8, 61, 0, 0],
 [8, 62, 0, 0, 8, 63, 0, 0],
 [8, 64, 0, 0, 8, 65, 0, 0],
 [8, 66, 0, 0, 8, 67, 0, 0],
 [8, 68, 0, 0, 8, 69, 0, 0],
 [8, 70, 0, 0, 8, 71, 0, 0],
 [8, 72, 0, 0, 8, 73, 0, 0],
 [8, 74, 0, 0, 8, 75, 0, 0],
 [8, 76, 0, 0, 8, 77, 0, 0],
 [8, 78, 0, 0, 8, 79, 0, 0],
 [8, 80, 0, 0, 8, 81, 0, 0],
 [8, 82, 0, 0, 8, 83, 0, 0],
 [8, 84, 0, 0, 8, 85, 0, 0],
 [8, 86, 0, 0, 8, 87, 0, 0],
 [8, 88, 0, 0, 8, 89, 0, 0],
 [8, 90, 0, 0, 8, 91, 0, 0],
 [8, 92, 0, 0, 8, 93, 0, 0],
 [8, 94, 0, 0, 8, 95, 0, 0],
 [8, 96, 0, 0, 8, 97, 0, 0],
 [8, 98, 0, 0, 8, 99, 0, 0],
 [8, 100, 0, 0, 8, 101, 0, 0],
 [8, 102, 0, 0, 8, 103, 0, 0],
 [8, 104, 0, 0, 8, 105, 0, 0],
 [8, 106, 0, 0, 8, 107, 0, 0],
 [8, 108, 0, 0, 8, 109, 0, 0],
 [8, 110, 0, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36],
 [7, 25, 0, 0, 7, 26, 0, 0],
 [7, 27, 0, 0, 7, 28, 0, 0],
 [7, 89, 0, 0, 7, 90, 0, 0],
 [7, 91, 0, 0, 7, 92, 0, 0],
 [7, 93, 0, 0, 7, 94, 0, 0],
 [7, 95, 0, 0, 7, 96, 0, 0],
 [7, 97, 0, 0, 7, 98, 0, 0],
 [7, 99, 0, 0, 7, 100, 0, 0],
 [7, 101, 0, 0, 7, 102, 0, 0],
 [7, 103, 0, 0, 7, 104, 0, 0],
 [7, 49, 0, 0, 7, 50, 0, 0],
 [7, 51, 0, 0, 7, 52, 0, 0],
 [7, 6, 0, 0, 7, 105, 0, 0],
 [7, 106, 0, 0, 7, 107, 0, 0],
 [7, 108, 0, 0, 7, 109, 0, 0],
 [7, 110, 0, 0, 7, 111, 0, 0],
 [7, 112, 0, 0, 7, 113, 0, 0],
 [7, 114, 0, 0, 7, 115, 0, 0],
 [7, 116, 0, 0, 7, 117, 0, 0],
 [7, 118, 0, 0, 7, 119, 0, 0],
 [7, 120, 0, 0, 7, 33, 0, 0],
 [7, 34, 0, 0, 7, 35, 0, 0],
 [7, 36, 0, 0, 7, 121, 0, 0],
 [7, 122, 0, 0, 7, 123, 0, 0],
 [7, 124, 0, 0, 7, 125, 0, 0],
 [7, 126, 0, 0, 7, 127, 0, 0],
 [7, 128, 0, 0, 7, 129, 0, 0],
 [7, 130, 0, 0, 7, 131, 0, 0],
 [7, 132, 0, 0, 7, 133, 0, 0],
 [7, 134, 0, 0, 7, 135, 0, 0],
 [7, 136, 0, 0, 7, 21, 0, 0],
 [7, 22, 0, 0, 7, 23, 0, 0],
 [7, 24, 0, 0, 7, 41, 0, 0],
 [7, 42, 0, 0, 7, 43, 0, 0],
 [7, 44, 0, 0, 7, 9, 0, 0],
 [7, 10, 0, 0, 7, 11, 0, 0],
 [7, 12, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0, 0],
 [7, 8, 0, 0, 7, 37, 0, 0],
 [7, 38, 0, 0, 7, 39, 0, 0],
 [7, 40, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0],
 [7, 17, 0, 0, 7, 18, 0, 0],
 [7, 19, 0, 0, 7, 20, 0, 0],
 [7, 3, 0, 0, 7, 53, 0, 0],
 [7, 54, 0, 0, 7, 55, 0, 0],
 [7, 56, 0, 0, 7, 45, 0, 0],
 [7, 46, 0, 0, 7, 47, 0, 0],
 [7, 48, 0, 0, 7, 57, 0, 0],
 [7, 58, 0, 0, 7, 59, 0, 0],
 [7, 60, 0, 0, 7, 61, 0, 0],
 [7, 62, 0, 0, 7, 63, 0, 0],
 [7, 64, 0, 0, 7, 65, 0, 0],
 [7, 66, 0, 0, 7, 67, 0, 0],
 [7, 68, 0, 0, 7, 69, 0, 0],
 [7, 70, 0, 0, 7, 71, 0, 0],
 [7, 72, 0, 0, 7, 73, 0, 0],
 [7, 74, 0, 0, 7, 75, 0, 0],
 [7, 76, 0, 0, 7, 77, 0, 0],
 [7, 78, 0, 0, 7, 79, 0, 0],
 [7, 80, 0, 0, 7, 81, 0, 0],
 [7, 82, 0, 0, 7, 83, 0, 0],
 [7, 84, 0, 0, 7, 85, 0, 0],
 [7, 86, 0, 0, 7, 87, 0, 0],
 [7, 88, 0, 0, 7, 13, 0, 0],
 [7, 14, 0, 0, 7, 15, 0, 0],
 [7, 16, 0, 0, 7, 7, 0, 0],
 [7, 29, 0, 0, 7, 30, 0, 0],
 [7, 31, 0, 0, 7, 32, 0, 0],
 [7, 1, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Dear Tim, Thank you. It really solved my problem. I am relatively new to advanced Python programming and particularly in reading specified data from files. . Thank you